# Camel smb:// - consuming a lot of files from one folder

Tags: java, apache-camel, smb

I am trying to download a large amount of files from an `smb://` endpoint and I would like the file consumption to be as fast as possible - meaning I would like to download and process as many files as possible, for example polling for 2000 files instead of whatever the default polling value in Camel is. To achieve this, I was looking for a way to increase the incoming batch size or add multi-threaded/parallel consumption on a single folder.

So far I have tried the following, but I noticed the download rate stayed the same as with one thread:

`from("smb:\\someFolder?&maxMessagesPerPoll=1000")...`

`from("smb:\\someFolder?&maxMessagesPerPoll=-1")...`

`from("smb:\\someFolder").threads(20)...`

Even with the `threads` option, despite seeing that the thread IDs vary, the download rate was the same. I suppose Camel simply assings a thread pool so that a different thread will pick up the incoming file each time, but the polling amount is the same.

I also looked up the `concurrentConsumers` flag, but from what I gather it is not supported for files, rather for ActiveMQ.

The only efficiency fix I managed to apply was consuming from multiple `smb://` endpoints. The throughput rate increased rapidly when I did that. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result as with multiple folders but using a single folder only?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you could simply **run multiple instances** of your application.

But if you do this, be sure to test with the **different locking strategies** of the [file component](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html) and watch the Camel logs for locking problems.

If there is concurrency between the consumers you could process the same file multiple times or you could get errors because the file one instance want to consume is gone because it was already consumed by another instance.

Take a look at the `shuffle` option if you use concurrent consumers. This shuffles the list of files to process randomly and therefore reduces the probability that multiple consumers try to consume the same file at the same time.

Comment: One way to 'lock' files is to have a thread rename the file when it acquires it, so that other threads no longer see that file. This assumes you are processing files based on a filename pattern, such as a particular file extension.

Comment: Yeah, you can do this easily with Camels File's `preMove` option. But you can still have concurrency issues. I add the `shuffle` option to my answer that can help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was thinking more along the lines of a built-in mechanism in Camel which I could use. Using a custom locking strategy seems to be quite an error-prone solution. Anyway, this is nice food for thought, as one could consider setting up multiple instances which could simply monitor files matching a different regex pattern, or a different file extenstion, etc.

Comment: You're welcome. The file locking strategies are a Camel built-in mechanism. You simply have a choice based on your requirements. And if you are able to define disjoint file patterns in the different instances even better. With disjoint patterns there is no risk for consumer concurrency.